# ListView and HTTP-GET Parameters

Tags: list-view, url

I'm new to SharePoint, but familiar with development. I have some issues with creating a list and defining custom listviews.

Whats my Problem. I want to query my list by some parameters whitch are declared by the URL (for example: AllItems.aspx?year=2011&month=12&day=18). Im searching for some codes or explainations about that, but havn't found anything. First of all: is it possible with SP2010? ;-) When the answer is yes: How could it be done?

Thank you very much. Best regards

Jan

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Enterprise License, there should be a Filters feature in Site Collection Features, which, when activated, will give you Filter web parts.

One of those is a Query String filter web part, which will let you take values from a query string and pass them (via Web Part Connections) to the List View.

You'll need to edit AllItems.aspx in the browser to add the filter web part and set up the connections (via the drop down menu at the right side of the web part title). No programming needed at all.

Comment: Ah ok.. are there any possibilities with SP 2010 Standard? Maybe doing it programaticly? ;)

Comment: Well if you're handy with C# you could knock up a quick and dirty Query String Filter web part of your own, by following this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457205(v=office.12).aspx (using the Visual Studio 2010 toolkit to make a SharePoint project). Just grab some query string params and pass them to the connector provider.